# cannot implicitly convert type system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn to system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn M'alerter

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-forms-designer

I'm really stuck at this point of creating a dynamic datagridview with 2 columns, I used the datgridtextboxcolumns but I keep getting this error

> cannot implicitly convert type
>   system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn to
>   system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn" for "dgviewcol1" and
>   "dgviewcol2

when I try to add new columns with AddRange. I also have the error saying that the Visible property doesn't exist in datagridviewtextboxcolumn which is false.

Anyone know how can i get rid of this errors?? Much appreciated!

```
private DataGridView dgview;
    private DataGridTextBoxColumn dgviewcol1;
    private DataGridTextBoxColumn dgviewcol2;
    void Search()
    {
        dgview = new DataGridView();
        dgviewcol1 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        dgviewcol2 = new DataGridTextBoxColumn();
        this.dgview.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dgview.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {this.dgviewcol1, this.dgviewcol2}); // "cannot implicitly convert type system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn to system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn"
        dataGridView2.Visible = false;
        this.dgviewcol1.Visible = false; // Visible property doesn't exist in datagridviewtextboxcolumn
        this.dgviewcol2.Visible = false;
        this.Controls.Add(dgview);
        this.dgview.ReadOnly = true;
        dgview.BringToFront();

    }
```

Comment: I reverted your most recent edit. See "[Is it OK to add \[Solved\] to the title of a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/284827)" for why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add `DataGridTextBoxColumn` into `DataGridView` instead of adding `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` so compiler tries to convert it into DataGridViewColumn which throws an exception.

```
private DataGridView dgview;
private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgviewcol1;
private DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dgviewcol2;
void Search()
{
    dgview = new DataGridView();
    dgviewcol1 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    dgviewcol2 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    this.dgview.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
    this.dgview.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn[] {this.dgviewcol1, this.dgviewcol2}); // "cannot implicitly convert type system.windows.forms.datagridtextboxcolumn to system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn"
    dataGridView2.Visible = false;
    this.dgviewcol1.Visible = false; // Visible property doesn't exist in datagridviewtextboxcolumn
    this.dgviewcol2.Visible = false;
    this.Controls.Add(dgview);
    this.dgview.ReadOnly = true;
    dgview.BringToFront();

}
```

Hopefully, this would solve your problem